# Finding $f(x)$ from first and second derivitive

Tags: calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

What is f(x) when
$$f(1)=0$$

first derivative $$f(1)=1/2$$

second derivative $$f(x)=1/x^3$$

Currently i have tried where the second derivitive = first derivitive + constant at x=1

1/x^3 = f^i(x) + C
1/1 = 1/2 + C
C=1/2

As well as where f(x) = first derivitve + constant at x=1

0 = x/2 + C
C = -x/2

I dont know where to go from here, aswell dont know if i had started it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f'(x) = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{x^3} dx = -\dfrac{1}{x^2} + C$.

$f'(1) = \dfrac{1}{2} = -1 + C \Rightarrow C = \dfrac{3}{2}$.

$f(x) = \displaystyle \int \left(-\dfrac{1}{x^2} + \dfrac{3}{2}\right) dx = \dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{3}{2}x + D$.

$f(1) = 0 \Rightarrow 0 = 1 + \dfrac{3}{2} + D \Rightarrow D = -\dfrac{5}{2} \Rightarrow f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{3x}{2} - \dfrac{5}{2}$.

Comment: There is a factor 1/2 missing in your first result.